# Firebase rules for updating variable every 10 minutes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to set up my google firebase rules so that data can only be written to a variable after 10 minutes. Basically the variable can only be updated after 10 minutes from the last update. A time stamp along with the variable is stored as seen in this image. [image: click here to see structure showing value as well as time stamp it was last updated]

Comment: Please show us the rules you've tried. And where did you get this timestamp from? is this the Database's `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Aside from that: make sure you store the timestamp as a number, otherwise it'll be harder than necessary to do the math in the rules.